# Help me with my first Mozilla Extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, extension-methods, mozilla

I am new to Mozilla extensions and i have been trying to build the "hello world" following this tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension but unfortunately its not showing anything on the right of my status bar when i start Firefox with my development profile. I have checked everything many times and not found any mistake in my code or file pattern. I'm doing everything they say in that tutorial. Now I'm seriously getting doubts on this tutorial is there something wrong with it ? have they missed out on anything that i should know? help me out here please

Comment: Well i have followed exactly what is said in that tutorial, my Firefox version is 3.6.10 and I'm running windows 7 professional.

Comment: Without knowing the folder structure, the files, the RDF, XUL... I can't tell what's wrong. You might like this addon. It improves the console then you can see chrome errors. You could check if there are any. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1815/

Comment: I have followed the exact folder structure mentioned in that tutorial sample.xul file is in C:\extensions\my_extension\chrome\content install.rdf and chrome.manifest files are at C:\extensions\my_extension

Comment: Maybe you didn't install your extension properly. Double-check the instructions about installing it, either as an .xpi, or "installing for development"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to post this information about that tutorial on building firefox extensions that it has major flaws in it which result in no output of what is being said in it, i have reported it and for starters here is another very helpful link thanks to which i was able to build my extension.

http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/